# Working with android actionbar

Tags: java, android

I have a code for making a slide menu navdrawer in android, which is provided as a slide.jar i downloaded from somewhere in internet and it is working fine. when i click the icon in action bar, the drawer slides well. The problem is that, i dont want my action bar to slide, but the left menu drawer only should slide, below the action bar.

and also, sliding is possible when i click the icon, but how to make the icon and title as a slingle clickable item as in gmail's app. 
my code is:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SimpleSideDrawer slide_me;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ActionBar a= getActionBar();
    a.setTitle("ashwin");
    a.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
    a.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    slide_me = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
    slide_me.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.left_menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        slide_me.toggleLeftDrawer();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Thankyou in advance

Comment: try implementing the action bar yourself..instead of using a library...or study the documentation of the library you are using

Comment: you should better off with tool bar, it gives you a lot of freedom then traditional actionbar, and if you are using this library made by jermy i guess you probably can't achieve what you want

Comment: `...which is provided as a slide.jar i downloaded from somewhere in internet and it is working fine.` Please use components provided by android, or libraries that have been well-tested. Adding a component(and that too a nav-drawer!) with little to no history will most like get you in trouble. By the way, what you;re trying to achieve is the default in cas eof android's own navigation drawer. Why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the correct implementation of a Navigation Drawer, I recommend staying away from 3rd party libraries as the Android provided ones work. The first thing you're going to want to write is your XML layout with a [`DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--The main content view, put your content here-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!--The navigation drawer-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then in code:

```
String mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

String[] nav_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_menu_items);
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    /**
     * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state
     */
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        setTitle(mActionBarTitle);
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Creates a call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    /**
     * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state
     */
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Creates a call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

// Set the drawerToggle as the DrawerListener
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(this));
```